# Gnuplot - latex commands & output window

Tags: latex, gnuplot

LaTeX is pretty common tool for typsetting symbols and formulas (i.e. `\alpha`, `\frac`) and I have learned that there are different terminals that support it, of which I especially like `tikz` which I often use in LaTeX.  However those terminals have output as a file only.  Is there any terminal or other option that allows using LaTeX commands **and** still shows the result instantly in a separate window?

Comment: I've never used term tikz, but what about tikz editors/viewers like ktikz or TikzEdt?

Comment: @theozh Never heard of them, I usually `pdfLaTeX` my `tikz` code.  Is it possible for `ktikz` abd `TikzEdt` to automatically refresh the file content?

Comment: Yes, tikzEdt should refresh the file if you created a new version with gnuplot.  Well, I wanted to try it, however, so far, without success. Last version from tikzEdt seems to be from 2013. Actually, I had no success at all with gnuplot-tikz files and TikzEdt as well as MiKTeX + pdfLaTeX. Apparently, I am doing something wrong and haven't yet found a comprehensive description how to use it with all prerequisites.

Comment: @theozh OK, `TikzEdt` definitely replots on external change, but there is an annoying requirement to close the `TikzEdt` notification window each time I change something.

Comment: @theozh The same is true for `ktikz`.  I think that your idea to use `tikz` GUI is great, but there are only two outdated programs.  I wonder why nobody else doesn't have this problem.

Comment: That's really too bad. I haven't even managed to get an output from these two programs with gnuplot generated Tikz files. I am also wondering that I often seem to be the "first" one to have a problem with something. If you do a search, MATLAB could be an option, however, I hope there are other viewers.

Comment: @theozh It seems to me that it is much easier to "program" plotting in `python`/`matplotlib`, much more documentation and available help...  I don't understand what is the point of using `gnuplot` at all.

Comment: well, I like gnuplot because it is compact, fast and offers a lot of output terminals. It is installed by unzipping a zip-file and uninstalled by deleting a directory. Well, it wants to be a plotting tool not a data manipulation tool, that's where I am struggling occasionally. I've written own programs (actually executables from Python) which are using gnuplot as plotting tool. I (and many other users) can simply load an updated gnuplot script and I don't have to repeatedly compile the Python code and distribute the executable again. Not sure whether this would be possible with matplotlib.

Comment: @theozh Now that is something I would really need - data manipulation + plotting as an iteritative process.  Ofc result must be compatible with LaTeX.  Origin and SigmaPlot are quite good in doing that, but they are unstable and require **A LOT** of boring repetitive work.  I am very into Python and LaTeX and am looking for alternatives.  Is it possible to learn about your method from somewhere?

Comment: What do you mean with "your method"? It is simply starting a subprocess or PyQtProcess in Python and calling gnuplot which loads a text script file (e.g. template which can be easily modified with any text editor), and opens a gnuplot window (e.g. interactive wxt terminal).

Answer (score 0):

Here is what I would do, and have done on occasion.  The refresh does not happen "instantly" since pdflatex is far from instantaneous. However it does have the advantage of keeping you inside the gnuplot session as you work on your figure.

```
# Create a pdf file holding the initial plot
MYFIGURE = "myfigure.tex"
set term tikz standalone
set output MYFIGURE    gnuplot> replot; unset out; system("pdflatex myfigure"); set out MYFIGURE
gnuplot> ... tweak the title, layout, colors, whatever
gnuplot> history !replot
plot PLOT1
unset output

# Display the pdf on the screen using whatever the standard pdf viewer
# is on your system.  For me (KDE desktop) this is okular.
system("pdflatex myfigure")
system("okular myfigure.pdf &")

# Draw new or updated versions of the figure into the same file
# okular will notice that the file has changed and refresh the display

set out MYFIGURE
set title "Same figure, new title"
replot
unset out; system("pdflatex myfigure")

set out MYFIGURE
set title "Different figure entirely"
splot FOO with pm3d
unset out; system("pdflatex myfigure")

# ... and so on
```

If you are continually tweaking the layout of the same figure so that the sequence always involves a replot, then putting the sequence on a single line gnuplot command allows you to re-execute in a singe step using gnuplot's history commands or hitting up-arrow a few times to retrieve the command.
For example:

```
gnuplot> replot; unset out; system("pdflatex myfigure"); set out MYFIGURE
gnuplot> ... tweak the title, layout, colors, whatever ...
gnuplot> history !replot
gnuplot> ... tweak the figure some more ...
gnuplot> history !replot
```

**Note:** TeX will want to find the gnuplot support packages in its normal search path.  If they are not already present in your TeX installation, you can follow the instructions in the gnuplot source .../term/lua/README (copied here)

```
Generating style and help file
==============================

To generate the style files and wrapper for the various TeX flavors enter

  lua gnuplot-tikz.lua style

on the command line. The files generated should be

  t-gnuplot-lua-tikz.tex        (Context wrapper)
  gnuplot-lua-tikz.tex          (plain TeX wrapper)
  gnuplot-lua-tikz.sty          (LaTeX wrapper)
  gnuplot-lua-tikz-common.tex   (common definitions)

and can be copied to the appropriate places.
```

Comment: Couldn't get further than
`D:/raspberry/marko/data/myfigure.tex:6: Undefined control sequence.
<recently read> \SetUnicodeOption`

Comment: `ucs` is installed, reinstalled manually, does not help.  `gnuplot-lua-tikz` also cannot be found or installed.  I am using`MikTex`, maybe your solution does not work for it?

Comment: Well yes, you need to install or manually place the TeX packages somewhere your TeX system can find them.  Or in the current directory if for some reason you cannot add them to the system directory.  I'll add a note to my answer.

Comment: Thanks a lot for all the effort. Does not work for MikTeX, there is no executable lua in the path or anywhere else in the MikTeX path. Forget it, I have given up using gnuplot.